# Most efficient way to test if number falls within certain 22.5 degree range of 360 degree circle

Tags: java

I am building a compass, and need to return a different String for the cardinal direction depending on what 22.5 degree interval the user is currently in.

For reference, please look at [this](http://climate.umn.edu/snow_fence/Components/winddirectionanddegreeswithouttable3.htm) picture.

Here is a sample of my current code:

```
if ((azimuth >= 348.75 && azimuth <= 360) || (azimuth >= 0 && azimuth <= 11.25))
{
    return "N";
}
else if (azimuth < 348.75 && azimuth >= 326.25)
{
    return "NNW";
}
```

This series of `else if` statements continues in 22.5 degree intervals until all cardinal directions are covered. Is there a more efficient way to do this? Currently, Android Studio/IntelliJ is giving an error message saying `this method is too complex to analyze by data flow algorithm`. Regardless of the error message, I think there might be a more elegant way to do this, but I can't think of it at the moment.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Divide by 22.5, producing an integer result (rounding as seems appropriate).  Use the integer to index an array of Strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Integer arithmetic is your friend:

```
private static final POINTS = new String[]{
    "N", "NNE", "NE", "ENE", 
    "E", "ESE", "SE", "SSE",
    "S", "SSW", "SW", "WSW",
    "W", "WNW", "NW", "NNW"};

public static String point(int azimuth) {
    return POINTS[(int)((azimuth + 11.25) % 360 / 22.5)];
}
```

This will work for any positive value.

---

If you prefer a more in-line approach:

```
return new String[]{"N", "NNE", "NE", "ENE", "E", "ESE", "SE", "SSE",
    "S", "SSW", "SW", "WSW", "W", "WNW", "NW", "NNW"}
    [(int)((azimuth + 11.25) % 360 / 22.5)];
```

Comment: Will, of course, fail for values greater than 371.25 (or negative values).

Comment: @HotLicks OK Mr. Strict... Added modulus to handle any non-negative input

Comment: Why declare points outside of the only function that uses it?

Comment: @Pétur it's for readability- it's a "magic value" if not a constant. I've added an inline version.

Comment: @Bohemian i have no problem with your original answer. I do not like the inline approach; my question was not clear. Would it be better to move the final static into the method itself?

Comment: @Pétur Ah. Good question. You can't move it into the method - local variables can't be static. You could declare a local final variable, but the usual approach is to use a "constant" (ie static final) - it's what people reading your code will expect and most easily understand.

Answer (score 2):

Did this some time ago in javascript, a quick solution:

```
districts = 'N;NNE;NE;ENE;E;ESE;SE;SSE;S;SSW;SW;WSW;W;WNW;NW;NNW';
districts.split(';')[Math.round(azimuth / 22.5) % 16];
```

Not using the modulo 16 resulted in incorrect results

Answer (score 0):

You want to find a match within [0;360).
Binary search can make this more efficient.
Also, the *else-if* is not needed, `return` will terminate the method early.

```
if (azimuth >= 0 && azimuth < 180) {
    if (azimuth < 90) {
        ....
    }
    else { // >= 90 and < 180
        ....
    }
}
else { // >= 180 && < 360
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `azimuth` will always be between [0..360]:

```
if (azimuth <= 11.25) return "N";
if (azimuth <= 33.75) return "NNE";
if (azimuth <= 56.25) return "NE";
if (azimuth <= 78.75) return "ENE";
...
if (azimuth <= 348.75) return "NNW";
return "N";
```

Caveat: all conditionals must be performed in order.

Answer (score -1):

I think a RangeMap lookup is a better solution. You can find a RangeMap implementation in Guava library.